# How do I clear:left, while keeping my float:left intact?

Tags: list, dom, drop-down-menu, clearfix

I have a jquery script that relies on the height of 'ul' to resize its containing 'div'.

Without 'clear:left' on my 'li' elements, their parent 'ul' has a height of one 'li'.

With 'clear:left' on my 'float:left' 'li' elements, the structure is lost.

**Heres the DOM without 'clear:left'. The 'li' elements are in perfect position, but the div is not resizing to fit them.**

jsfiddle.net/63pNN/35/

**Heres the DOM with 'clear:left'. The div is resizing to fit the list height, 'li' elements are overlapping**

jsfiddle.net/63pNN/36/

Any ideas are helpful!  I'm so close.....!

THANKS